# Graphics are not creating at the current mouse position

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawing

I am using the following code to draw . I have no Idea why it is doing this. before it was working fine . When I added "picBox.Image = new Bitmap(560, 464);" this line in my form() and I added this  Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image)...

```
private void picBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        draw = true;
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;

    }

private void picBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {


            if (draw)
            {
                //Graphics g = picBox.CreateGraphics();
                switch (currItem)
                {
                    case Item.Rectangle:
                        Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image).FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(paintColor), x, y, e.X - x, e.Y - y);
                        break;
                    case Item.Ellipse:
                        Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image).FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(paintColor), x, y, e.X - x, e.Y - y);
                        break;           

                }
                picBox.Refresh();
                Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image).Dispose();
            }
        }
 private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = false;
        lx = e.X;
        ly = e.Y;


    }
```

Comment: what is `Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image).Dispose();` supposed to do??? this line does nothing except for creating garbage items in your memory ;)

Comment: `Graphics.FromImage` returns `Graphics` instance. You've dispose that, not `Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image).Dispose()`. This is meaningless creating a graphics and disposing immediately

Comment: nothing.. if I remove that it still does the same thing

Comment: Several problems.  The biggest one is that it can only work correctly if the PictureBox.SizeMode property is set to Normal or AutoSize.

Comment: ^ yea does work correctly when its Normal or AutoSize, but can you please tell why it does now work for StretchImage and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `Graphics` object with each operation you perform on your image. Also look at the math you need to draw at the right spot of the image since you are using `PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage`!

Try this:

```
Graphics g;
private void picBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    g = Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image);
    draw = true;
    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;

}

private void picBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (draw)
    {
        // since you are using PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage:
        float rescaleX = (float)pixBox.Image.Width / pixBox.Width;
        float rescaleY = (float)pixBox.Image.Height / pixBox.Height;

        // if you do not want to produce a "trail" of shapes
        g.Clear(picBox.BackColor);
        switch (currItem)
        {
            case Item.Rectangle:
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(paintColor), 
                          x * rescaleX, 
                          y * rescaleY, 
                          (e.X - x) * rescaleX, 
                          (e.Y - y) * rescaleY);
                break;
            case Item.Ellipse:
                g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(paintColor), 
                          x * rescaleX, 
                          y * rescaleY, 
                          (e.X - x) * rescaleX, 
                          (e.Y - y) * rescaleY);
                break;           
        }
        picBox.Refresh();
    }
}
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    draw = false;
    lx = e.X;
    ly = e.Y;

    g.Dispose();
}
```

However, if this is supposed to become some sort of simple paint, you will need more logic:
As long as the mouse is down, draw in some temporary buffer that you draw above your image. "Commit" this buffer (by drawing it on top of your image), as soon as the mouse button is released.

Comment: hmm it does not work correctly, but my code works fine if I use SizeMode as normal , but it mess up the mouse position for StretchImage.

Comment: oh okay **that** is the problem, I will asjust my code sample!